# Homogeneous of degree - distribution theory.

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

There is a definition in distribution theory I came across. If $f$ is a distribution on $R^n$, then it is homogeneous of degree $K$ if $f(rx)=r^Kf(x)$ for all $x$ and $r>0$.

I am trying to show that $\delta$ has degree $-n$. But I am having difficulties as $\delta(x)$ and $\delta(rx)$ always coincide.

Furthermore there is a distributional derivative given by $(I_{(x>0)}\log(x))'$. It is hard for me to see why this is not homogeneous. Furthermore this function supposedly agrees with a function a.e that is homogeneous of degree -1. What is this function? can it be found this explicitly?

Comment: $\delta(rx) = r^{-n}\delta(x)$

Comment: why? everywhere I see just states this without explanation.

Comment: That's the definition, $T(rx)$ is the distribution $\langle T(rx),\phi \rangle=\langle T,r^{-n}\phi(x/r)\rangle$, mimicking what you get when $T\in L^1(\Bbb{R}^n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f=1_{ x >0}\log x\in D'(\Bbb{R})$ and $r>0$ $$f(rx)=f+1_{x >0}\log r$$ $$f'(rx)= r^{-1} (f(rx))'=r^{-1} f' + \color{red}{r^{-1} \delta(x)\log r}$$

Comment: sorry what is $f'(rx)$ and $(f(rx))'$? is the first the distributional derivative?

Comment: The same operators as for smooth functions, extended in the obvious way to distributions.

Comment: I see. And the highlighted part vanishes a.e showing that $f'$ indeed agrees with a homogeneous degree -1 function?

Comment: $f'$ is homogeneous as a distribution on $\Bbb{R^*}$ but not on $\Bbb{R}$ due to the Dirac term. $1_{x>0} \frac1x$ is homogeneous as a distribution on $\Bbb{R^*}$, but it is not a distribution on $\Bbb{R}$.